# Arrows inside modal image (resizing by image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, carousel

On my modal carousel I have arrows sometimes inside and sometimes outside image.. it depends on image resolution. And I want to have arrows inside every image with different resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the site, instead of setting the width to 100% and height to auto, its better to do the vice versa concept,Here is the CSS for making the changes needed!

The CSS property `text-align: center;` should be set to the ID `carousel-modal-demo`

```
#carousel-modal-demo{
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

The carousel inner class needs to be modified as shown below!

```
.carousel-inner {
    position: relative !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

The images under the carousel CSS needs to be modified like so.

```
#carousel-modal-demo img{
    width: auto !important;
    height: 400px !important;
}
```

The id `#modal` should have a padding of 50px at the top.

```
#modal{
    padding-top:50px !important;
}
```

So total CSS changes are:

```
#carousel-modal-demo{
    text-align: center !important;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}

#carousel-modal-demo img{
    width: auto !important;
    height: 400px !important;
}

#modal{
    padding-top:50px !important;
}
```

Its because you are setting the CSS property `max-width:100%` for all the images inside the carousel. If you set it to `width:100%` using the below CSS Class.

```
#carousel-modal-demo div.item > img {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

The class that is getting overridden is the below class.

```
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! :)

Comment: I have one more small question. If the image is on height on the right side there is a gap between the arrow and image. I'm adding screenshot > https://gyazo.com/c79956918083dabc018d006870ef98df

Comment: @ExrowGe I have updated my answer with a few CSS changes that should help you with your issue, please let me know if it does!

Comment: @ExrowGe Does my new suggestion help you?

Comment: Yes that works well. Sorry for no reply. And thanks so much again.